# I am trying to identify an animated fantasy film from the late 1970s or early 1980s in which:

Tags: story-identification, movie, elves

A boy goes hunting for the 1st time with his father & the men of his village in the forest.

He becomes separated, and fairies or elves take him into their realm, where he helps them fight some evil power, goblin, overlord, or something that is threatening it.

At the end of the film he is returned to the same place they found him, apparently at the same time (or close to it), and his horse/pony has game (deer, etc.) laying across it, just as the men of the village find him, believing him to have hunted & taken all the game himself.

Comment: What language was this?

Comment: @ E.Z. Hart It was in English

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the 1981 film ['Faeries'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faeries_(1981_film))

> A young man, Oisin "(pronounced O-sheen)" returns home with a group of huntsmen from an unsuccessful hunt when a deer, revealing to be a faerie princess appears to him and takes him to her father, the Faerie King.  [Wikipedia]